# wxWidgets tips for dynamic list of checkboxes

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using `wxWidgets` and trying to display tooltips for a dynamic list of devices (checkboxes):

```
for (DeviceHolder devH : *devices) {
    uint64_t addr = devH.bleAddress;
    wxCheckBox* cbox = new wxCheckBox(panel, wxID_ANY, AddrToString(addr));
    checkboxsizer->Add(cbox, 0, wxLEFT, 20);
    Connect(cbox->GetId(), wxEVT_MOVE, wxMoveEventHandler(DeviceListDialog::onMove));
    boxes.push_back(std::pair(cbox, addr));
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "Device name: " + devH.deviceName;
    this->tips->insert(std::pair< wxWindowID, std::string>(cbox->GetId(), stream.str()));
}



void DeviceListDialog::onMove(wxMoveEvent& event) {
    std::cout << ".";
    std::string msg = this->tips->find(event.GetId())->second;
    wxRichToolTip tip(wxT("INFO"), msg);
    tip.ShowFor(this);
}
```

Nothing works, the function `DeviceListDialog::onMove` doesn't work, no tips appear. Tell me what can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mouse events don't propagate upward, so whatever your trying to connect the event to in the line

```
Connect(cbox->GetId(), wxEVT_MOVE, wxMoveEventHandler(DeviceListDialog::onMove));
```

will never receive the event.  Incidentally, you should use `Bind` instead of connect for various reasons.

---

Instead you should use the `Bind` method of the checkbox itself.  Something like this should work:

```
cbox->Bind(wxEVT_MOTION, &DeviceListDialog::onMove, this);
```

I'm assuming this code occurs in the constructor for DeviceListDialog. If the code is being run elsewhere, replace `this` with a pointer to the DeviceListDialog being constructed.

Comment: Thanks, but I gon an error. "MyApp has triggered a breakpoint.", In appbase.cpp in `wxDefaultAssertHandler`: `if ( guard.IsInside() ){...`, 1080 line. There is comment here: `// can't use assert here to avoid infinite loops, so just trap`.

Comment: The event type for the mouse event triggered whenever the cursor is moved over a window should be `wxEVT_MOTION`.  `wxEVT_MOVE` is a completely different thing altogether.  I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks. `wxMoveEvent&` event is uncompatable with `wxEVT_MOTION`, so I changed it to `wxEvent&` and now that works. But this is very annoying tooltip. Is it possible to make the tip appear only if the mouse cursor lingers on the element for more than 1 second and disappear immediately after the mouse cursor leaves the element?

Comment: Instead of showing the tooltip in the motion event handler, you can start a [timer](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_timer.html) in the event handler and show the tooltip if the timer expires.  You should then restart the timer in every motion event.  It will probably also be necessary to handle the wxEVT_LEAVE_WINDOW event to stop the timer.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can check if the cursor is on the same wxCheckBox?